# ¿Cómo puedo colocar dos columnas (con íconos y texto) una al lado de otra?

Tags: html, css

la verdad quiero hacer un estilo parecido al de esta imagen: [image: Estilo CSS deseado]

Y mi código se ve como esto:

[image: Estilo CSS obtenido]

Sin embargo he intentado muchas cosas, he buscado en diferentes sitios de Internet, he incluso en muchas preguntas relacionadas en éste sitio sin llegar a una solución.

A continuación voy a incluir el código HTML y los estilos CSS (relacionados con la pregunta).

```
    /*HTML*/
    <div id="i-do">
    <center><h2>Things that I LOVE to do</h2></center>
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i>Listen music</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>Sing</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-cookie-bite"></i>Cook some dessert</li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-adobe"></i>Design</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-pen-fancy"></i>Draw mandalas</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-paw"></i>Help animals</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="love-do">
    <center><h2>Things that I can do</h2></center>
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fas fa-draw-polygon"></i>Logos</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-book"></i>Read a lot of books</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-store-alt"></i>Branding</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-pump-soap"></i>Product design</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-grin-squint-tears"></i>Funny GIFs</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-trophy"></i>Basically, whatever you want ;)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
/*CSS*/
ul {
padding-left: 0px;
list-style: none;
z-index: 0;}

ul li {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 1.6875em 0;
padding: 0.35em 0 0 3.5em;
position: relative;
vertical-align: top;
width: 48%;}

#i-do, #love-do {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-left: 208px;
padding: 15px;
line-height: 2em;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e42d40;}

ul li i {
background: royalblue;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
display: block;
color: white;
border-radius: 100%;
padding: 12px;}
```

Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

P. D: Sé que la etiqueta  ya no se utiliza en HTML5 pero me gustaría tener todo en orden en CSS antes de añadir ese estilo.

Comment: Utiliza la propiedad [float](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=739:concepto-float-css-none-left-right-y-icentrar-colocar-texto-alrededor-de-una-imagen-ejemplos-cu01034d&catid=75&Itemid=203)

Comment: Solo agrega algo como: ```div{ float:right; }```

Comment: Gracias por comentar, ya utilicé la propiedad float pero en realidad no funciona.

Comment: Prueba algo como .i-do {width: 50%; } ya que así le indeicas que ése div en concreto debe ocupar media pantalla. Aunque de todas formas, creo que una mejor opción es usar por ejemplo bootstrap ya que tienes todas las herramientas para lo que quieres y además te garantizas que se verá bien en todos los dispositivos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad es muy simple, lo logras con:

- Envuelve tus 2 listas en un contenedor padre
- Al contenedor padre dale un clase
- A la clase que le des a dicho contenedor padre dale un display flex lo cual moverá tus divs y sus listas de columna a fila sobre el *main axis*

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <style>
      .container {
        display: flex;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="i-do">
            <center><h2>Things that I LOVE to do</h2></center>
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i>Listen music</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>Sing</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-cookie-bite"></i>Cook some dessert</li>
                <li><i class="fab fa-adobe"></i>Design</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-pen-fancy"></i>Draw mandalas</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-paw"></i>Help animals</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
          <div id="love-do">
            <center><h2>Things that I can do</h2></center>
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fas fa-draw-polygon"></i>Logos</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-book"></i>Read a lot of books</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-store-alt"></i>Branding</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-pump-soap"></i>Product design</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-grin-squint-tears"></i>Funny GIFs</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-trophy"></i>Basically, whatever you want ;)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Así será la salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pues según como veo las cosas tienes dos caminos posibles.

1. Puedes utilizar la propiedad `float:left` en ambos div y te quedaran exactamente a la par, justo como quieres, aunque te dire que no es lo más recomendado, porque puedes llegar a tener conflictos de capas con los demás divs que puedas seguir creando.
2. Puedes intentar utilizar un framework como bootstrap que te permitirá manejar esto a la perfección con sus clases de grids.

Te dejo este enlace si quieres utilizar esta opción, que es la que te recomiendo totalmente.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

**He tomado tu codigo y lo he editado según te explique en la opción 1**

```
<div style="float: left;" id="i-do">
    <h2><center>Things that I LOVE to do</center></h2>
    <ul>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="float: left;" id="love-do">
    <center><h2>Things that I can do</h2></center>
    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Y a continuación el resultado:

[image]

**Te los he dejado como estilos en linea, pero puedes pasarlo a tu hoja de estilos css si lo prefieres.**

Answer (score 0):

Espero ayudarte, hice un ejemplo de tu lista usando flex.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
 <style>
  * {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .container {
   padding: 1rem;
   display: flex;
  }

  .content {
   width: 50%;
   padding: 1rem;
  }

  .list {
   list-style: none;
  }

  .list li {
   margin-bottom: 1rem;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   color: #b6b6b6;
  }

  .icon-list {
   width: 42px;
   height: 42px;
   margin-right: 1rem;
   display: inline-flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   border-radius: 50%;
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #4acaa8;
  }

  .h2 {
   padding-bottom: 1rem;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
   <center>
    <h2 class="h2">Things that I LOVE to do</h2>
   </center>
   <ul class="list">
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i></span>music</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-microphone"></i></span>Sing</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-cookie-bite"></i></span>Cook some dessert</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fab fa-adobe"></i></span>Design</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-pen-fancy"></i></span>Draw mandalas</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i></span>Help animals</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <center>
    <h2 class="h2">Things that I can do</h2>
   </center>
   <ul class="list">
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-draw-polygon"></i></span>Logos</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span>Read a lot of books</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-store-alt"></i></span>Branding</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-pump-soap"></i></span>Product design</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-grin-squint-tears"></i></span>Funny GIFs</li>
    <li><span class="icon-list"><i class="fas fa-trophy"></i></span>Basically, whatever you want ;)</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Ejemplo de lista de 2 columnas]

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como lo hice usando solo CSS y Flexbox;

https://codepen.io/ossoboy/pen/VwvpvOy?editors=1100

Escríbeme si tienes alguna duda sobre el código.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución considera agregar el código en la respuesta, si se agrega un enlace este puede perderse y la respuesta no serviría de mucho, revisa [answer], saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Trabajala con grid y flex

```css
.wrap{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.icono{
  background-color: #4acaa8;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.grid-container > div, .grid-container1 > div {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  align-items: center;

}

p{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="grid-container ">
        <center><h2>Things that I LOVE to do</h2></center>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Listen music</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Sing</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span></i><p>Cook some dessert</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Design</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Draw mandalas</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Help animals</p></div>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-container ">
        <center></center><h2>Things that I can do</h2></center>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Logos</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Read a lot of books</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span></i><p>Branding</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Product Design</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Funny GIFs</p></div>
        <div><span><i class="fa fa-amazon icono"></i></span><p>Basically, whatever you want ;)</p></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```